# onclick() get geolocation is not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

**Whats the problem:**

*if*
 ( I wrap around `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initMap, onError);` whith `function triger()` and then call it like :
`<button id="btn" class="btn btn-default" onclick="triger()">`)

*then*

its do nothing!

*else*

its good!

here is my code:

```
 <script>

  var map;
  var infowindow;
  var selecteditem="hospital";
  var radiusin=5000;

  function triger() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initMap, onError); 

}

  function onError(error){
    alert("the code is " + error.code + ". \n" + "message: " + error.message);
}

  function initMap(position) {

    selecteditem= $("#selector").val();
    radiusin= $("#radius").val();    
    alert(selecteditem+"in"+radiusin);
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var pyrmont = latLong;// {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 14
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch({
      location: pyrmont,
      radius: radiusin,
      type: selecteditem
    }, callback);
  }
  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
</script>
```

and:

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
  <button id="btn" class="btn btn-default" onclick="triger()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why type=submit? Use type=button

Comment: @mplungjan sorry that was a mistake,by the way its not working...

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: The posted code works for me (displays a map when the button is pressed).  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y1gj77ze/2/)  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed

```
 selecteditem= $("#selector").val();
```

to:

```
 $("#selector").change(function () { slecteditem= $(this).find("option:selected").val(); }
```